# In scribblenauts unlimited what do you give the fortune teller that wants you to give him a zodiac to discover?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

I just plainly tried typing zodiac but it did not go through so i saw these sparkly things that always showed beside the people's head and it had stuff that looked like stars ,what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

The [zodiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zodiac) is the area of the sky in which the Sun makes its apparent path during the year as the Earth revolves around it. It is divided into twelve "signs", each named after a constellation visible in that area of the sky. They are: Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, Virgo, Libra, Scorpio, Sagittarius, Capricorn, Aquarius, and Pisces.

Some people like to think that the signs the Sun was in at the time of a person's birth can be used to predict things about that person's life, so the zodiac is of interest to fortune tellers.

Simply type in one of the signs to make the fortune teller happy.